# Discord.js Birthday Bot-I have bdays stored in JSON file, how do I send "Happy bday" when someone has birthday

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coding a Disord Bday Bot. Which saves someone in JSON file. I coded a command which can find someone by user id and tell when they have their bday. I want the bot to send a message when someone has theirs bday but I have no idea how should I do it. **Any ideas?**

JSON file, which holds bdays :

```
    "397698843858436097": {
        "day": "9",
        "month": "2",
        "year": "2006",
        "id": "  "
    },
    "453556418352513025": {
        "day": "16",
        "month": "1",
        "year": "2006",
        "id": "BookOfMonsterman04"
    }
}
```

command which saves a bday to JSON file:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
    name: 'setbday',
    description: 'this is a setbday command!',
    execute(message, args) {
        
        client.bdays = require('./bdays.json');

        client.bdays[message.author.id] = {
            day: args[0],
            month: args[1],
            year: args[2],
            id: message.author.username
        }
        fs.writeFile('./bdays.json', JSON.stringify(client.bdays, null, 4), err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            message.channel.send('Saved your birthday date!');
        });
    }
}
```

and command which can read someone bday if you tag them as argument:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
    name: 'bday',
    description: 'this is a bday command!',
    execute(message, args, Discord){
      
      
      
      const target = message.mentions.users.first();
      fs.readFile("./bdays.json", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("File read failed:", err);
        }else{
          const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
          let bday = data[target.id].day;
          let bmonth = data[target.id].month;
          let byear = data[target.id].year;
          const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Birthday')
            .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstleyVEVO')
            .addFields(
                {name: 'Day', value: bday},
                {name: 'Month', value: bmonth},
                {name: 'Year', value: byear}
                );  
          message.channel.send(newEmbed);
        }
      });
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setInterval`, which is really designed to repeat a task every x milliseconds, you can instead use the node package called [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) which is largely designed for time-based scheduling instead of interval-based scheduling. It makes it much easier to schedule tasks at a specific date.

Assuming you want to send a happy birthday message automatically when it is the user's birthday, you should be scheduling your task(s) in your `client.on("ready")` handler instead of using a command to read the JSON file and send a message, but you also need to schedule the task when a birthday is set (because otherwise newly set birthdays will only be congratulated after the bot restarts again). In that handler, you need to read the JSON file, loop through all of the items in it, assemble a `Date` object from each user's birth day/month and the current year, and schedule a message send at that `Date`. You would also need to slightly modify your `setbday` command to set a specific channel in which the message should be sent; you can either set it to a single constant channel (like a `#birthdays` channel) or just the channel in which the command is used (which is what I will do in this example).

You will also need to remove your creation of a new `Discord.Client` in both of your command files; not only is that unnecessary, but it will not work in the way you intend.

**Solution**

So here's an example:

This is a new file called `birthdays.js` which is in your main folder (not `commands`):

```
const schedule = require("node-schedule");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    scheduleBday(day, month, year, username, channelID, client) {

        var currentDate = new Date();

        //Date constructor is in the format: year, month, day
        //Month is from 0-11, where 0 is January and 11 is December (so we subtract 1)
        var birthDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), Number(month) - 1, day);

        var j = schedule.scheduleJob(birthDate, () => {

            const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(`Happy Birthday, ${username}!`)
            .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstleyVEVO')
            .addFields(
                {name: 'Day', value: day},
                {name: 'Month', value: month},
                {name: 'Year', value: year}
             );  

            var channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
            if (!channel) return console.log("Could not find channel");
            channel.send(newEmbed);
        });

        return j;

    }
}
```

This is in your bot's main file (i.e. `index.js` or `server.js`):

```
const birthdaysjs = require("./birthdays");

client.on("ready", () => {

    //Use the proper path to your bdays.json; this is an assumption based on your code
    const bdays = require("./commands/bdays.json");

    Object.values(bdays).forEach(bday => {

        //Schedule a happy bday message for each bday in bdays.json
        birthdaysjs.scheduleBday(bday.day, bday.month, bday.year, bday.id, bday.channelID, client);
    });

});
```

This is your `setbday` command's file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const birthdaysjs = require("../birthdays");

module.exports = {
    name: 'setbday',
    description: 'this is a setbday command!',
    execute(message, args) {
        
        message.client.bdays = require('./bdays.json');

        var bday = {
            day: args[0],
            month: args[1],
            year: args[2],
            id: message.author.username,
            //Get the ID of the channel you want to send the happy bday message in:
            channelID: message.channel.id
        }

        message.client.bdays[message.author.id] = bday;

        fs.writeFile('./bdays.json', JSON.stringify(message.client.bdays, null, 4), err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            message.channel.send('Saved your birthday date!');

            //Schedule a happy bday message for this newly added birthday!
            birthdaysjs.scheduleBday(bday.day, bday.month, bday.year, bday.id, bday.channelID, message.client);

        });
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

First of all, let me explain why I created a separate `birthdays.js` file to do this: the happy bday message needs to be scheduled in more than one different file. Here's what I mean: if you only schedule a bday message in your `client.on("ready")` handler, then any birthdays added with your `setbday` command after the bot starts up will not have a bday message scheduled; only the previously set birthdays will have a message scheduled. To solve this, I not only schedule all birthdays in the `ready` handler, but also schedule them as they are created. I decided to create a separate file for the scheduling code and to require that file, instead of directly pasting the exact same code in two different files.

Next, allow me to explain how `birthdays.js` works. First, we get the current date using `new Date()`. We need the current date because we want to send the happy bday message on the user's birthday *this year*, so we need to get the current year. Next, we construct the date at which the user will have a birthday this year using: the current year, the user's birth month, and the user's birth day. Note that javascript's months go from `0-11` instead of `1-12`, so we need to subtract one from our month value in order to get an accurate `Date` object. Finally, we use `node-schedule` to schedule a task on the user's birthdate. As for the task itself, we simply use the embed from your `bday` command's code, get the channel we need to send the message in, and then send the embed in that channel.

As for the `ready` event handler in your bot's main file, we only need to add a few things. First, we read your bdays JSON file to get all of the birthdays. Next, we use `Object.values()` to get an array of only the values of the JSON file (remember that your JSON file's format is `{"user id": birthdayObject}`, matching the JSON structure of `{"key": value}`). We then loop through all of those values using `Array.forEach()`. Finally, we use the code from our `birthdays.js` file to schedule a happy bday message for each of the birthdays that we loop through in the JSON file.

And finally, let's look at your `setbday` command code. First of all, I removed your `new Discord.Client()` because that creates *an entirely new bot* instead of using your existing bot's `Client`. Use `message.client` instead. Other than that, all I changed in that file was adding a channel ID to send the happy bday message in, and scheduling the happy bday message for any newly set birthdays.

If you didn't understand any part of this code, or if you notice any errors or such, feel free to comment below and let me know!

**Answer to question in your comment**

If you just want to list all of the users with a birthday today, here's the full code for one way you could do it (assuming this is in a command file such as your `bday` command):

```
var bdays = require("./bdays.json");
var bdayUsers = [];

Object.values(bdays).forEach((data) => {
    let {day, month, id} = data;

    var currentdate = new Date();
    var goaldate = new Date(currentdate.getFullYear(), currentdate.getMonth(), currentdate.getDate());
    var birthdate = new Date(currentdate.getFullYear(), Number(month) - 1, day);

    if (goaldate.getTime() == birthdate.getTime()) {
        //Today is the birthday of this user!
        bdayUsers.push(id);
    }
});

//If no users have a birthday today, make the below message say "None" in bold
if (bdayUsers.length == 0) bdayUsers = ["**None**"];

message.channel.send("Users with a birthday today: " + bdayUsers.join(", "));
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how can I make a command "bdayDay" or something and it will search the whole JSON file and tell me which users (ID not name) have their birthday on that day (month doesnt metter). Thanks! @Cannicide

Comment: Sure! I've added the code to the bottom of my answer. The month does matter in my code, but you can replace `Number(month) - 1` with `currentdate.getMonth()` if you don't want the month to matter.

Comment: Okay thanks! If I need any future help I will definitely call you :D

Comment: Okay I finally added this code to the bot. It seems everything works fine. But I need to test it so how do I "fake" call birthday? Like I set my bday to 16.1. and how do I "fake" call it. Can I just change time on my computer or something? If you know What I mean :D @Cannicide

Comment: And I just found out that If I reset the bot and someone adds their bday (?setbday nubers) it deletes everything in the JSON file and all there is is the new guy.

Comment: Hmm maybe try replacing `message.client.bdays` with a variable instead? I don't know if that would solve it, but it might. As for what you referred to as a "fake call" of the birthday message, just change the value of `currentDate` in birthdays.js to use the same date as your birthday (same month and day, but not necessarily year) instead of the actual current date in order to test it out. You can look at the format/explanation for creating a new `Date` object to do so (it's commented right below that line in birthdays.js).